# Insert an image into Access database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a Save button where I am able to Insert data into my Access database. One of that fields is "BrandImage" and there I will insert an image. The datatype from this field is `Memo`.

This is the code I already have:

```
    try
    {
        con = new OleDbConnection(cs.DBConn);
        con.Open();

        string queryInserir = @"INSERT INTO tblPhone (BrandImage) VALUES (@BrandImage)";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryInsert);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(pcPhone.Image);

        bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
        OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter("@BrandImage", OleDbType.WChar);
        parameter.Value = data;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Info saved successfully", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The `pcPhone` is a `PictureBox`

When I debug it and try to save it it will give me this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on this line of code `Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(pcPhone.Image);`

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Can you show where `pcPhone` is populated? If you put a breakpoint in the debugger at that line what is defined as `pcPhone.Image`?

Comment: pcPhone is a PictureBox @JoshuaHysong

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the debugger at that line what is the value of `pcPhone.Image`? The error you are getting likely means `pcPhone.Image` is null.

Comment: I know what's causing it. I am using a Background instead of an Image on the PictureBox, but I don't want to use an Image what should I do? @JoshuaHysong

Comment: Easy peasy, just change `pcPhone.Image` to `pcPhone.BackgroundImage`